# Django "no such column: mains_profile_friends.user_id"

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am going through a Django tutorial and getting this error when trying to open friends page in browser (In local Host) in my blog app.

I use Django==3.1.2.

`views.py`

```
@login_required
def friend_list(request):
    p = request.user.profile
    friends = p.friends.all()

    context = {'p':p,'friends':friends}
    return render(request, 'mains/friends.html' , context )
```

`models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='friends',blank=True,default='',null=True)
```

`friends.html`

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      {% if friends %}
      <div class="card card-signin my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          {% for user_p in friends %}
          <a href="{{ user_p.get_absolute_url }}">{{ user }}</a>
          <a class="text-dark" href="{{ user_p.get_absolute_url }}"
        ><b>{{ user_p }}</b></a>
            <br /><br />
         {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

`urls.py`

```
path('friends/', views.friend_list, name='friend_list'),
```

**The Problem**

When I open friends.html in browser it is giving me an error: `no such column: mains_profile_friends.user_id`

**What i have tried.**

1).  I have replaced all the names related to `friend_list` view.

2). I have also migrated in Terminal.

Help me in this! I will really appreciate your Help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And where should mains:delete_friend lead to?

Comment: You propaply did some migration conflicts, just restart your database by removing all migration files but keeping init.py, deleting sqlite3.db, finally makemigrations && migrate

Comment: @ZeyadShaban, I have deleted all the migrations except init.py BUT nothing happens.

Comment: have you deleted sqlite3.db? also did you remigrate again (pytohn3 manage.py makemigrations python3 manage.py migrate)

Comment: @ZeyadShaban, I haven't deleted the sqlite3.db. I also remigrete the server

Comment: You must delete your database, then delete migrations, then finally remigrate the server. If you have data that you dont' want to lose then take a JSON copy of what you have, I think it was done with python3 manage.py dumb > seed.json, I'm not sure

Comment: now it is `python manage.py dumpdata > seed.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must delete your database, then delete migrations but keep init.py in the migration folder in each app folder, then finally migrate again with python3 manage.py makemigrations then python3 manage.py migrate. If you have data that you don'  want to lose then take a JSON copy of what you have, I think it was done with python3 manage.py dumb > seed.json, I'm not sure